# Can't prove vector equation (I've try attact my answer)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given a vector function $\mathbf{R} = x\mathbf{i}+ y\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}$ and $r = |\mathbf{R}| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ then prove that for any vector constant $\mathbf{A}$ holds $\nabla\times\Big(\frac{1}{r}(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{R})\Big)=\frac{1}{r}\mathbf{A}+\frac{\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{R}}{r^2}\mathbf{R}$

This is my friend answer but i dont understand
Is he right?

$\nabla\times\Big(\frac{1}{r}(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{R})\Big)$
\begin{align*}
={}&\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}k\Big)\times\Big(\frac{1}{r}(A_2z-A_3y)i+(A_3x-A_1z)j\\&+(A_1y-A_2x)k\Big)\\
={}&  
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
i & j & k \\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
\frac{1}{r}(A_2z-A_3y) & \frac{1}{r}(A_3x-A_1z) & \frac{1}{r}(A_1y-A_2x)
\end{array}
\right|\\
={}& \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{1}{r}(A_1y-A_2x)\Big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(\frac{1}{r}(A_2z-A_3y)\Big)\Big)i + \\&\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(\frac{1}{r}(A_2z-A3_y)\Big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{1}{r}(A_1y-A_2x)\Big)\Big)j\\& + \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{1}{r}(A_3x-A_1z)\Big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{1}{r}(A_2z-A_3y)\Big)\Big)k\\
={}&\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}}(A_1y-A_2x)\Big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}}(A_2z-A_3y)\Big)\Big)i\\& +\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}}(A_2z-A_3y)\Big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}}(A_1y-A_2x)\Big)\Big)j\\& + \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}}(A_3x-A_1z)\Big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}}(A_2z-A_3y)\Big)\Big)k\\
={}& \Big(\Big((A_1y-A_2x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(A_1y-A_2x)\Big)-\\&
\Big(\Big((A_3x-A_1z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(A_3x-A_1z)\Big)\Big)i\\&
+\Big(\Big((A_2z-A_3y)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(A_2z-A_3y)\Big)-\\&
\Big(\Big((A_1y-A_2x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(A_1y-A_2x)\Big)\Big)j+\\&
\Big(\Big((A_3x-A_1z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(A_3x-A_1z)\Big)-\\&
\Big(\Big((A_2z-A_3y)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(A_2z-A_3y)\Big)\Big)k\\
={}& \Big(\Big((A_1y-A_2x)\Big(\frac{-y}{(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)A_1\Big)+\\&
\Big(\Big((A_3x-A_1z)\Big(\frac{z}{(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)A_1\Big)\Big)i\\&
+\Big(\Big((A_2z-A_3y)\Big(\frac{-z}{(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)A_2\Big)+\\&
\Big(\Big((A_1y-A_2x)\Big(\frac{x}{(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)A_2\Big)\Big)j\\&
+\Big(\Big((A_3x-A_1z)\Big(\frac{-x}{(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)A_3\Big)+\\&
\Big(\Big((A_2z-A_3y)\Big(\frac{y}{(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big)A_3\Big)\Big)k\\
={}& \frac{A_1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}i+\frac{A_2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}j+\frac{A_3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}k\\&
+\frac{\Big((-A_1y^2+A_2xy)+(A_3xz-A_1xz^2)\Big)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}i+\frac{A_1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}i\\&
+\frac{\Big((-A_2z^2+A_3yz)+(A_1xy-A_2x^2)\Big)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}j+\frac{A_2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}j\\&
+\frac{\Big((-A_3x^2+A_1xz)+(A_2yz-A_3y^2)\Big)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}k+\frac{A_3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}k\\
={}&\frac{A_1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}i+\frac{A_2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}j+\frac{A_3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}k\\&
+\frac{A_1x+A_2y+A_3z}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2+z^2}^\frac{4}{2}}(xi+yj+zk)\\
={}&\frac{A_1i+A_2j+A_3k}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+\frac{A_1x+A_2y+A_3z}{\Big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\Big)^2}(xi+yj+zk)\\
={}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\Big(A_1i+A_2j+A_3k\Big)+\frac{(A_1i+A_2j+A_3k)(xi+yj+zk)}{\Big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\Big)^2}(xi+yj+zk)\\
={}&\frac{1}{r}A+\frac{AR}{r^2}R
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to M.SE! Is $\mathbf{A}$ a constant vector? Also, you are encouraged to show your work and what is the part that you are stuck on. This site is not meant to solve homework problems, and you usually get much more help if you show that you tried to do your part :)

Comment: Sorry, A should be vector constant, not R. I just edited my question

Comment: \begin{align*}
\nabla\cdot\Big(\frac{1}{r}(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{R})\Big)
={}& \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}k\Big)\Bigg(\frac{1}{r}
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
i & j & k \\
A_1 & A_2 & A_3 \\
x & y & z
\end{array}
\right|
\Bigg)\\
={}& \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}k\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}(A_2z-A_3y)i\\&+(A_3x-A_1z)j+(A_1y-A_2x)k\Big)\\
\end{align*}

Is it right? @cjferes

Comment: Ups I can't write my full answer because characters limit

Comment: @cjferes I just writed my full answer on the top.

Comment: Good job editing. Retracting my vote to close.

Comment: @konyong wow I never expected that one edit a about to close question to such a high quality question. Wonderful Good work

Comment: An alternative I would follow is to use the formula
$$\nabla\times(A\times B)=(B\cdot\nabla)A-B(\nabla\cdot A)-(A\cdot \nabla)B+A(\nabla\cdot B).$$ In your case $B=\dfrac1r\,R$. As $A$ is a constant vector field, the two first terms automatically vanish. For the others you get away with the common formulas (learn them, if you study mechanics!!) $\partial_x R=x/r$ (and the same with other coordinates) implying $\nabla\cdot (\dfrac 1r\,R)=\dfrac 2r$ etc.

Comment: (cont'd) The term $(A\cdot\nabla)B$ is a bit trickier and comes out as 
$$A\,\dfrac1r-\dfrac{A\cdot R}r \,\dfrac R r$$ after a bit of crank turning. Anyway, this cancels one half of the $A\dfrac2r$ from the other term as required, and the other term is also there.

Comment: Not posting the details as an answer as A) we have probably covered the relevant parts somewhere on the site already, and B) that does not really adress the question about your friend's answer.

Comment: Oopsie. Should read $\partial_x r=x/r$ two comments up.

Comment: I recommend @JyrkiLahtonen's approach as it saves you so many computations in the first two terms. Other than that, this should be enough for kickstarting your solution Konyong.

Comment: Thanks!! @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Sorry@JyrkiLahtonen, I can't prove with your formula. Is the equation correct? I doubt about that.